# How to check number of rows changed by last update in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I can use `@@ROWCOUNT` to check number of affected rows by the last `UPDATE` statement. But it is not number of changed rows in database.

After executing statements like:

```
UPDATE User 
SET FirstName = @FirstName 
WHERE Id = @Id
```

value in `@@ROWCOUNT` is always `1` - in both situations: when new FirstName is different than old one or not (has been changed or not).

Is there any built-in method to check how many rows has been really changed (not only affected) by last `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if you have any Triggers being fired instead of the actual Update statement.
2. To get the row affected by your update statement you can use `OUTPUT` clause inside your UPDATE statement to see the rows that were actually updated, by doing something like this.....

   ```
   DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (FirstName VARCHAR(100));

    UPDATE [User] 
     SET FirstName = @FirstName 
    OUTPUT Inserted.FirstName INTO @TABLE
    WHERE Id = @Id;

   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TABLE;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Not really, because mysql isn't checking to see if it needs to do an update, it's just doing it.  What you can do is this:

```
UPDATE User SET FirstName = @FirstName WHERE Id = @Id AND FirstName <> @FirstName
```